# If $T$ is an isometry, then $T(V)=V$ and $T(V^\perp)=V^\perp$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V\subset \mathbb R^3$ a subspace of $\mathbb R^3$ and $T\in \mathrm{Isom}(\mathbb R^3)$ s.t. $T(V)\subset V$. Show that $T(V)=V$ and $T(V^\perp)=V^\perp$.

I have a problem to show that $V\subset T(V)$.

**My try**

Let $a\in V$. Since $T$ is bijective, there is a unique $b\in \mathbb R^3$ s.t. $a=T(b)$. Since $\mathbb R^3=V\oplus V^\perp$, there is unique $u,w$ s.t. $b=u+w$. Now, I want to show that $w=0$. I tried to use the fact that $T$ conserve the inner product but It's not conclusive. I want to show that $\left<w,w\right>=0$, so since $u\in V$ and $w\in V^\perp$ $$\left<w,w\right>=\left<w,w+u\right>=\left<T(w),z\right>,$$
so if $T(w)\in V^\perp$ it would be done. I tried to show it first, but I need the fact that $T(V)=V$. So I turn around.

Comment: I guess you want to show $V \subset T(V)$..

Comment: $T(V)\subset V$ needs to be an hypothesis, as the example of rotations shows. once you have $T(V)\subset V$, *then* equality follows by a dimension argument. And yes, this is true for any $\Bbb R^n$ in general.

Comment: @Onil90: yes of course

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can conduct a more simple reasoning.

Since you know that $T$ is bijective (because it is injective and $T$ lives in a finite dimensional space), you know that

$$\dim T(V)=\dim V.$$

But $T(V)\subset V$ by hypothesis, so $T(V)=V$ because $V$ is of finite dimension.

Comment: Yes, nice ! +1 thanks